# How to get id value from ng repeat which is having filters and sort

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I need a id value from angular table (ngrepeat),i tried with based on index, i am getting the id, but if i sort or filter i am getting wrong value.
can any one help me.

Comment: Show us a minimal code example of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(function(){

angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($window){
  var ctrl = this;
  
  ctrl.myModel = { people: data}
  
  ctrl.callPerson = function(person) {
    $window.alert("Calling " + person.name + "..." + person.phone);
    //$window.location.href = "tel://" + person.phone; will really place the call note this is generated data don't call these numbers
  }
})








var data = [
  {
    "_id": "5a33579a9b942b9fe5f5a358",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "888545f8-39cd-42f1-b62d-66561f914bbd",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,255.62",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 39,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Crystal Moody",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "EBIDCO",
    "email": "crystalmoody@ebidco.com",
    "phone": "+1 (979) 525-3273",
    "address": "885 Boerum Street, Coaldale, Alabama, 5757",
    "about": "Enim culpa ex velit qui Lorem sint consequat eiusmod tempor cillum est anim nisi pariatur. Esse amet dolore qui pariatur et ullamco incididunt laborum minim. Anim occaecat amet irure non sunt aliqua magna cupidatat.\r\n",
    "registered": "2014-11-14T07:10:40 +06:00",
    "latitude": 44.111754,
    "longitude": 109.396716,
    "tags": [
      "eiusmod",
      "voluptate",
      "Lorem",
      "adipisicing",
      "irure",
      "non",
      "fugiat"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Lolita Carroll"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Morgan Lowe"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Nelson Monroe"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Crystal Moody! You have 9 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a33579ac212dea8803319b2",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "df60b699-9327-45cc-90ab-48a9529d0be3",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,926.45",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 20,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Clark Mullen",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "ESSENSIA",
    "email": "clarkmullen@essensia.com",
    "phone": "+1 (824) 480-2355",
    "address": "588 Celeste Court, Hoehne, North Dakota, 6139",
    "about": "Labore minim amet nisi officia enim magna culpa veniam esse proident minim. Duis Lorem incididunt cupidatat tempor veniam. Adipisicing aliqua qui do ea adipisicing occaecat laboris cupidatat qui.\r\n",
    "registered": "2017-08-23T07:02:33 +05:00",
    "latitude": -59.829075,
    "longitude": -48.944559,
    "tags": [
      "et",
      "sunt",
      "eu",
      "quis",
      "eiusmod",
      "excepteur",
      "eu"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Richardson Kirk"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Alice Owens"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Gaines Chase"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Clark Mullen! You have 7 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a33579af28bbab5cf8b88a6",
    "index": 2,
    "guid": "b34c0dfa-30f6-433d-ae67-6ca49dc3b563",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,472.90",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 31,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": "Ellen Booker",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "ANACHO",
    "email": "ellenbooker@anacho.com",
    "phone": "+1 (933) 536-2492",
    "address": "620 Amity Street, Westboro, Northern Mariana Islands, 1017",
    "about": "Ullamco laboris non qui proident minim. Sit nulla officia cillum voluptate amet ut mollit. Qui sint esse fugiat ullamco elit veniam aliquip exercitation laboris ipsum.\r\n",
    "registered": "2015-01-03T04:41:35 +06:00",
    "latitude": 50.272514,
    "longitude": 172.218658,
    "tags": [
      "ex",
      "duis",
      "mollit",
      "eu",
      "ipsum",
      "cupidatat",
      "excepteur"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Malone Henson"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Alba Welch"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Rene Kirby"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Ellen Booker! You have 2 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a33579aa8ac1198e99698bd",
    "index": 3,
    "guid": "5340cbbe-564e-4d94-8e4c-5a2c98e71f92",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$3,528.81",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 38,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Porter Grimes",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "GEEKOLA",
    "email": "portergrimes@geekola.com",
    "phone": "+1 (844) 446-3236",
    "address": "331 Coles Street, Diaperville, Connecticut, 3857",
    "about": "Elit proident ea fugiat minim pariatur Lorem proident enim proident consectetur non non. Aliqua et irure Lorem ipsum laborum nostrud magna nulla labore exercitation laboris ut reprehenderit. Exercitation non mollit excepteur ex laborum consequat magna ad aute. Irure ex sint aliqua magna excepteur labore amet enim incididunt mollit Lorem ea amet. Consectetur dolor ipsum in esse sit reprehenderit nulla sunt sit ut laborum eiusmod.\r\n",
    "registered": "2014-11-13T11:02:38 +06:00",
    "latitude": 7.622975,
    "longitude": 169.075008,
    "tags": [
      "culpa",
      "tempor",
      "consectetur",
      "minim",
      "mollit",
      "amet",
      "nulla"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Agnes Harrell"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Marla Velez"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Lisa Dennis"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Porter Grimes! You have 2 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a33579ae2ad992fc3e3f247",
    "index": 4,
    "guid": "aec451c2-ce01-4ad1-86ec-a49745b1991c",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$3,395.15",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 38,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Hammond Mcconnell",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "BRISTO",
    "email": "hammondmcconnell@bristo.com",
    "phone": "+1 (876) 470-2913",
    "address": "444 Keap Street, Hollins, Wisconsin, 5879",
    "about": "Do elit anim reprehenderit ex laboris cupidatat duis. Ad et enim tempor commodo amet ipsum officia ea dolor occaecat amet eu Lorem adipisicing. Magna duis minim proident et amet sunt duis nostrud tempor tempor commodo ut nisi. Veniam nulla mollit deserunt occaecat nisi laboris adipisicing laboris laborum do ullamco mollit deserunt in. Est cupidatat quis proident elit laborum velit veniam esse magna duis excepteur. Dolor reprehenderit nisi aute cillum voluptate cupidatat aliqua eiusmod excepteur enim ex amet.\r\n",
    "registered": "2017-07-23T10:51:54 +05:00",
    "latitude": 28.196343,
    "longitude": -158.265017,
    "tags": [
      "in",
      "aliqua",
      "esse",
      "enim",
      "incididunt",
      "esse",
      "esse"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Margaret Rose"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Herring Lee"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Emily Mcdonald"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Hammond Mcconnell! You have 3 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a33579ae52a3366af5e8959",
    "index": 5,
    "guid": "2816a836-e2d4-409b-9173-fe0a9490ae1b",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$1,078.79",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 39,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": "Allie Young",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "FREAKIN",
    "email": "allieyoung@freakin.com",
    "phone": "+1 (819) 484-3471",
    "address": "242 President Street, Vowinckel, South Dakota, 6383",
    "about": "Qui magna eu exercitation ex et anim voluptate minim cillum duis. Pariatur minim eu id in ex deserunt aliqua aliqua officia labore qui pariatur aliqua. Dolore velit incididunt minim ipsum incididunt elit do nisi est.\r\n",
    "registered": "2015-05-20T03:08:54 +05:00",
    "latitude": 75.266107,
    "longitude": 135.350245,
    "tags": [
      "enim",
      "est",
      "ipsum",
      "cillum",
      "officia",
      "qui",
      "aliqua"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Walters Jacobson"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Dionne Justice"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Potter Ortega"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Allie Young! You have 9 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "apple"
  }
]

})();
```

```css
table,td,th{
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
table, input{
  width:100%
}
button{
  width:100%;
  font-weight:700;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">

<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.searchTxt"/>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Eye Color</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in ctrl.myModel.people | filter:ctrl.searchTxt | orderBy:'name'">
      <td>{{person.name}}</td>
      <td>{{person.company}}</td>
      <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
      <td>{{person.eyeColor}}</td>
      <td>{{person.phone}}</td>
      <td><button ng-click="ctrl.callPerson(person)">Call</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Simply don't use the $index as an `id` and calling functions with objects or their properties within the ng-repeat works fine in general.  `$index` is like `$even` or `$odd` it has to do with the current display not the data itself really.  If your data doesn't have id's just loop through and give them ids if you want them for display purposes (keep in mind when filtering there will be gaps in the numbers).